# What does "not about betting the kitchen sink on a hot tip" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this line in one of the personal finance book I'm reading currently and wondering what "not about betting the kitchen sink on a hot tip" mean in this context.

> Getting an equity exposure is about following the rules of holding a
> portfolio that gives you index-plus returns and not about betting the
> kitchen sink on a hot tip. If you do that, don't cry later.
> <sub>Source: [*Let's Talk Money: You've Worked Hard for It, Now Make It Work for You* - Monika Halan, 2018](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Let_s_Talk_Money/IgxeDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22not%20about%20betting%20the%20kitchen%20sink%20on%20a%20hot%20tip%22&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

Comment: It's a hopelessly mixed metaphor. A risky high-stakes gamble is idiomatically referred to as ***betting the farm*** (if you lose that, you lose *everything*). But *[]throwing **everything but the kitchen sink** [at a problem]* is an unrelated metaphoric usage meaning to use / take every last thing you could possibly need (to mount an attack, do a job, go on holiday, etc.).

Comment: Apparently, the OP is a non-native speaker. The sentences seem to be taken from some Asian-country newspaper (India, I suppose.) I don't think these idioms (_kitchen sink_, at any rate) would be instantly recognizable to a non-native.

Comment: There is not a mixed metaphor here: To bet the kitchen sink on [somethingt], here, a hot tip. It does pass the sniff test. bet the kitchen sink on is American slang and probably not in ngrams.  https://sportsbetting.legal/news/dont-bet-the-kitchen-sink-on-march-madness-warns-aga////LEGALDon’t bet the kitchen sink on March Madness, warns AGA

Comment: The link in the question goes to a book by an Indian author, which supports  the supposition that the readership might also be from the same region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intended *meaning* is simply that successful investing involves following a set of rules / guidelines, ***not*** rashly gambling money you can't afford to lose on the advice of a "tipster" (someone who claims to know which horse will win a race, or which financial product will produce the biggest return on investment).

The normal idiomatic reference to ***gambling money you can't afford to lose*** is [***betting the farm***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bet-the-farm-ranch) *(Ngrams not found: **bet the kitchen sink**)*. But this has got mixed up with *[throwing] [**everything but the kitchen sink**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/everything-but-the-kitchen-sink) [at a problem]*.

[Here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bet%20the%20kitchen%20sink%2Cbet%20the%20farm%2Ceverything%20but%20the%20kitchen%20sink%2Ceverything%20but%20the%20farm&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3#) showing that both idiomatic usages are about equally common. They wouldn't normally be merged together as in OP's example.

[image]

Comment: "Everything but the kitchen sink" is of course also used in other contexts (packing for holiday, or the contents of some desirable purchase).  But the metaphor of throwing all those things at a problem is a close relation to throwing lots of money at an investment, so I think you're really on the mark here.

Comment: I don't think the two idiomatic usages are at all close. Betting the ***farm / ranch*** clearly refers to *the most valuable thing you have* (or perhaps the *second* most valuable thing, after ***you bet your life***). But *everything but the kitchen sink* doesn't necessarily even have strong allusions to "money, value" - it just means *everything you could possibly **imagine*** (whimsically, betting with Monopoly money, or your as-yet-unborn daughter's hand in marriage, for example! :)

Comment: I would not expect to find bet the kitchen sink on in ngrams. google: 52,900 hits "bet the kitchen sink" on [x].

Comment: @Lambie: Your point being? As pointed out, the two idiomatic usages are ***not*** interchangeable when used with their established meanings. I've no idea what proportion of your claimed 52,900 instances are deliberate facetious usages (as opposed to ignorant mixed metaphors). But even counting both types, they're small beer compared to the *established* usages as may be found in dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see no mixed metaphor at all. I see: bet on the kitchen sink, one expression and another: a hot tip. It is used in the States. Bet the farm on is much older.  You *claim* it is a mixed metaphor and I don't think it is. It has achieved its own status. They are not claimed instances. Google them and go down the page. They do work in the pages where they appear.

Comment: @Lambie: Apparently you don't accept that ***the farm*** is quintessentially ***the most valuable thing / everything of value*** - which is different to ***the kitchen sink*** (everything ***conceivable***, whether valuable or not; often *contextually inappropriate* things). Maybe the battle has already been lost here - if enough people use the mangled mixed metaphor, at some point we have to accept that what was once a "misuse" might eventually become an idiomatic standard. Butt I certainly don't think we're there yet with this one.

Comment: The farm is a different image. In **American English**, people say bet the kitchen sink on. They also say bet the farm on. You just have to get over it.

Comment: @Lambie: The (earlier) alternative to ***bet the farm*** is [***bet the ranch***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bet+the+farm%2Cbet+the+ranch%2Cbet+the+kitchen+sink&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (Ngrams ***still*** not found: *bet the kitchen sink* :) By the same token, the earlier version of ***everything but the kitchen sink*** was *...the kitchen **stove***, and both ***ranch*** and ***stove*** have always been far more common in AmE than BrE - which simply underscores the fact that all these usages are essentially *American* idioms.

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding the touch of flourish there's to it, this sentence (*a caveat*, essentially) is very well-put. What the "troubling" sentence means is that it warns against any injudicious investment. This should be clear after a little unpacking.

According to *Merriam-Webster*:

*hot tip*

> a valuable piece of information about something (such as the stock market or a horse race) that can help someone get money or an advantage

*AND*

*To bet the kitchen sink*/*To throw the kitchen sink* at something means **to try everything you can in order to do something or to solve a problem.**

The admonitory tone of the sentence should be clear from the very last sentence.

Comment: "very well-put"?! I think it's astonishingly *badly* phrased! I guess a native speaker *might* put the indefinite article before ***equity exposure*** here, but that certainly stands out as "odd" to me, as well as the clumsy mixed metaphor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A difference of opinion in such matters always makes me ask _who decides that_? While I defer to your superior knowledge, I find the sentence to be well-put. At any rate—I'm sure some would concede— it isn't appallingly bad like you say it's. :)

Comment: I can *almost* imagine a financial advisor or similar talking about giving a client ***an*** equity exposure. But if that's the case, I think it would be a peculiar domain-specific usage. And although in some cases the mixing of metaphors might be witty wordplay, in this case I think it's just a clumsy "accident".

Comment: ...you should note that native Anglophones ***never*** use a contraction in contexts like your *Notwithstanding the touch of flourish **there's** to it*. I'm not exactly a "grammarian", but I think it's fair to say that contraction is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The idea, I take it, of 'kitchen sink' is that it is the most vital possession we have (not nowadays, when we take it for granted, of course.  It represents the key asset in the running of a household, involving the cleanliness of what we eat and wear, and so the very last thing we should put at risk.  Rising standards of living (at least in developed anglophone countries) have made that less obvious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh boy! I wrote the answer in haste rather, I guess. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Tuffy: I'm not convinced. I think you're wriggling on the hook trying to make a case for ***kitchen sink*** having strong allusions to ***high value*** (so you can defend the idea of ***wagering*** it in a high-stakes gambling context?). But its normal associations are to something ***unexpectedly / ridiculously over the top*** (that's never ***actually*** taken anywhere or used to solve any problem; the whole point is that many things only *slightly* less ridiculous ***do*** get taken / used).

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Perhaps.  The expression with which I am more familiar is "I've thrown everything but the kitchen sink at it."  Why the kitchen sink rather than the chairs, sofa or television set I cannot say.  But I do suspect that sinks were the first non-movable household appliance to be almost universally available in houses, with the arrival of running water in the early 20th century, and much sooner than that for the more affluent parts of the community.  But I admit that the original suggestion was a wild guess.

Comment: @Tuffy: Indeed. I'm not sure if I've explicitly said it anywhere on this page, but I'm familiar with just two very specific contexts involving *everything but the kitchen sink*. The first is ***taking*** EBTKS somewhere like "on holiday", where the intended sense doesn't really have much to do with solving problems - it's about someone having everything they could possibly want in order to feel comfortable / safe / whatever in some new environment. The *other* context I'm very familiar with is your "bring every imaginable resource to bear on some problem" sense - ***throwing*** EBTKS at it.

Comment: (I *did* point out at least once or twice that the original version of the idiom was EBTK ***stove***. Which was in use long before TVs existed. But imho the primary allusion is to the ***ridiculousness*** of taking your stove/sink on holiday, or expecting it to help solve some thorny problem - the relative "immovability" of such "fixtures" is only peripherally relevant to the imagery.

Answer (score 0):

A "hot tip" is a recommendation (tip) that sounds strong (hot).

To "bet the farm" is an idiom meaning to take an unaffordable risk.

"Everything but the kitchen sink" is an idiom for everything imaginable.  By extension, the kitchen sink itself is more than that, and that's what's been substituted into "bet the farm".

Putting this together, the advice is clear: *don't risk your entire wealth on a single recommendation*.

Comment: I don't think *everything but the kitchen sink* particularly implies "every moveable possession one owns". Kitchen sinks aren't exactly "moveable" anyway, but more importantly I don't think throwing everything but the kitchen sink at a problem (the most common context) particularly implies *committing one's **possessions** to the task*. It's more about including everything one might normally think of ***plus*** even more things that *wouldn't* normally be included. *Eye of newt and toe of frog, Wool of bat and tongue of dog* aren't "valuable possessions" but you might say they're "EBTKS"

Comment: Indeed, I've always understood the non-moveability of the sink to be the reason it's excluded in the stock phrase.  I only have SOED, which doesn't give specific origins (only to the headword _kitchen_), but its definition is "everything imaginable", so I'll substitute that in.

Comment: The *full* (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary also defines it as ***everything imaginable***. But until I just looked it up myself, I wasn't aware that the *original* was *everything but the kitchen **stove*** (first recorded 1897). The ***...sink*** version wasn't recorded until 1918.

Comment: ...I just thought I'd look for the next-most-common *alternative* to the kitchen sink/stove in this context, so I searched Google Books for all texts containing **"threw everything but"** AND **"at the problem"**, BUT NOT **"but the kitchen"**. Turns out the only match where the text can actually be read is *As one who threw **everything but the technological equivalent of the kitchen sink** at the problem I was surprised at how little was really new.* This particular idiomatic apple obviously doesn't fall far from the figurative tree of the original usage! :)